# Code doesn't continue after the do-while loop?

Tags: java

I have began to learn Java in my AS level computing class, and have really taken to the first DIY task we have been set.

I have used a do-while statement to see if the input username from the user is in the array "names"- if it's not, it requests to re-enter the username, until a correct one is inserted. I have also set up a boolean, so when a correct username is entered, it cancels the do-while loop and continues with code - but it doesn't.

```
String[] names = {"mckeownl", "heardj", "williamsc"};
String[] attendance = {"yes", "no", "yes"};
int[] grade = {96, 66, 73};

boolean loggedin = false;

Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);
String login;
login = user_input.next();

do {   // beginning of while - login

    System.out.println("Insert student's surname followed by the first letter");
    System.out.print("of their first name (e.g John Smith = smithj): ");

    if (Arrays.asList(names).contains(login)) {
       System.out.println("Student selected: "+login+".");
       loggedin = true;
    }
    else { 
       System.out.println("Incorrect student name! Please try again.");
       loggedin = false;
    }

} while ( ! loggedin);

if (login.equals(names[0])) {
    System.out.println("Attend today: "+attendance[0]);
    System.out.println("Grade: ");
}   
else {
    System.out.println("poo");
}   

    }
}
```

The output for a correct name is ;

"Insert student's surname followed by the first letter
of their first name (e.g John Smith = smithj): mckeownl
Student selected: mckeownl."

Why isn't the final if statement output?

Comment: Why are you asking for `login` outside the loop?

Comment: One problem with your code is that "," probably shouldn't be a valid login. Also " ".

Answer (score 0):

You should be asking for the login inside the loop.

You shouldn't set the `loggedin` variable to false if it fails. Just give text that it failed, then it'll return to the top and ask for login again.

You can have multiple lines in a method call. So you could have:

```
System.out.println("Insert student's surname followed by the first letter " + 
"of their first name (e.g John Smith = smithj): ");
```

Instead of:

```
System.out.println("Insert student's surname followed by the first letter");
System.out.print("of their first name (e.g John Smith = smithj): ");
```

Answer (score 0):

put  `login = user_input.next();` inside the loop.. In order for the user to `loggedin` again..

```
do {   // beginning of while - login

System.out.println("Insert student's surname followed by the first letter");
System.out.print("of their first name (e.g John Smith = smithj): ")

 login = user_input.next(); // <--- you should ask for login here
...
```

**updated:**

```
//for the final if statement
if (loggedin) { //just use this boolean variable since you used it as an indicator if it is valid name or not
    System.out.println("Attend today: "+attendance[0]);
    System.out.println("Grade: ");
}   
else {
    System.out.println("poo");
}
```

actually, you don't need to put condition after the loop since you already filter it inside the loop so if the name is not valid it will not exit the loop until the user enter a valid name.. you can just do it like this after the loop

```
do{
..
}while(..)

System.out.println("Attend today: "+attendance[0]);
System.out.println("Grade: ");
```

Comment: I did this, however it still doesn't solve my issue. My final if statement that is outside of the loop still doesn't run.

Comment: your final condition only compare the first element of the array which is `"mckeownl"`. so in order to compare to all elements of the array `name`.. you need a loop or just use the boolean `loggedin`.. since you use it as an indicator if the name exist in the array

Comment: Hm, I changed the final if to the first one (checking if it's loggedin or not) and it didn't work, and then I changed to the 2nd one and it still didn't work. Still trying to find a solution

Comment: What would be the expected output if i logged in with the username `"mckeownl"` ?

Comment: well it would exit the loop and the output (for this code version) would be: 
"Attendance today: yes
Grade: "

Answer (score 0):

I started from scratch, and have created this, which uses the same principles, but has solved my answer.

There are three users, each with their own login, password creation and password entry (if you have a better way to do this, please say).

```
package codeyom9a;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Codeyom9a {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String[] names = {"Luke", "Jack", "Brad" };
String[] surnames = {"Mckeown", "Heard", "Reed" };


Scanner user_input = new Scanner(System.in);

boolean firstloggedin;
boolean passloggedin;



String firstlogin;

do {                                                                        //login first name
    firstloggedin = false;
    System.out.print("Enter your first name: ");
    firstlogin = user_input.next();

    if (firstlogin.equals(names[0]) || firstlogin.equals(names[1]) || firstlogin.equals(names[2])) {
       firstloggedin = true;

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please try again.");
    }

} while (! firstloggedin);

 boolean secondloggedin;


String secondlogin;

do {                                                                        //login surname
    secondloggedin = false;
    System.out.print("Enter your surname: ");
    secondlogin = user_input.next();

    if (secondlogin.equals(surnames[0]) & firstlogin.equals(names[0])|| secondlogin.equals(surnames[1]) & firstlogin.equals(names[1]) || secondlogin.equals(surnames[2]) & firstlogin.equals(names[2])) {
       secondloggedin = true;

    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please try again.");
    }

} while (! secondloggedin);  

if (secondlogin.equals(surnames[0]) & firstlogin.equals(names[0])) {        //pass login user 1

    String password1;                                                       //pass create user 1
    System.out.print("Create a password (no spaces): ");
    password1 = user_input.next();

    boolean passloggedin1 = false;

    do{ 

        String passwordenter1;                                              //pass enter user 1
    System.out.print("Enter your password now: ");
    passwordenter1 = user_input.next();

    if (passwordenter1.equals(password1)) {
        passloggedin1 = true;
        System.out.println("Correct! You have now logged in.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect password!");
    }
    } while (! passloggedin1);


}                                                                           //end user 1


if (secondlogin.equals(surnames[1]) & firstlogin.equals(names[1])) {        //pass login user 2

    String password2;                                                       //pass create user 2
    System.out.print("Create a password (no spaces): ");
    password2 = user_input.next();

    boolean passloggedin2 = false;

    do{ 

        String passwordenter2;                                              //pass enter user 2
    System.out.print("Enter your password now: ");
    passwordenter2 = user_input.next();

    if (passwordenter2.equals(password2)) {
        passloggedin2 = true;
        System.out.println("Correct! You have now logged in.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect password!");
    }
    } while (! passloggedin2);


}                                                                           //end user 2

if (secondlogin.equals(surnames[2]) & firstlogin.equals(names[2])) {        //pass login user 3

    String password3;                                                       //pass create user 3
    System.out.print("Create a password (no spaces): ");
    password3 = user_input.next();

    boolean passloggedin3 = false;

    do{ 

        String passwordenter3;                                              //pass enter user 3
    System.out.print("Enter your password now: ");
    passwordenter3 = user_input.next();

    if (passwordenter3.equals(password3)) {
        passloggedin3 = true;
        System.out.println("Correct! You have now logged in.");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Incorrect password!");
    }
    } while (! passloggedin3);


}                                                                           //end user 3

    }
}
```

If you type in "Luke", "Jack", or "Brad", it then requests for the surname (which is in the same index in the 'surnames' array). If both correct, it request for a password to be created, and then asks for the user to input that created password.

Regarding my first code, I don't know why this works and the other doesn't, any ideas why?